# How to make a link of a substring in reStructuredText (RST)

Tags: restructuredtext

How can I make a link inside a string in RST?

Like so:

ImInThe[Middel](http://foo.com)OfAString - without adding spaces between `The` and `Middle` and `Middle` and `Of`.

But in reStructuredText (RST).

If I simply write the rst like so:

```
ImInThe`Middel <http://foo.com>`_OfAString
```

I get this as the result (so no link):

```
ImInThe`Middel <http://foo.com>`_OfAString
```

If I write this:

```
ImInThe `Middel <http://foo.com>`_OfAString
```

I get an error,  and finally if I write this:

```
ImInThe `Middel <http://foo.com>`_ OfAString
```

I get the link but with spaces in between:

ImInThe [Middel](http://foo.com) OfAString

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found out that I can use backslash to escape the space.

So this:

```
ImInThe\ `Middel <http://foo.com>`_\ OfAString
```

Gives me the right result:

ImInThe[Middel](http://foo.com)OfAString